# Querying SQLAlchemy User model by password never matches user

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I want users in my Flask app to be able to change their email by providing a new email and their current password.  However, when I try to look up the user by the password they entered with `User.query.filter_by(password=form.password.data)`, it never finds the user.  How can I query the user so I can change the email while verifying the password?

```
@app.route('/changeemail', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def change_email():
    form = ChangeEmailForm(request.form)

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(password=form.password.data).first()

        if user and bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password,form.password.data):
            user.email = form.email.data
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect(url_for("user.confirmed"))

    return render_template('user/changeemail.html',form=form)

class ChangeEmailForm(Form):
    email = TextField('email', validators=[DataRequired()])
    password = PasswordField('password', validators=[DataRequired()])

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *whole point* of storing the hashed password is so that you *never* store the raw password.  Query for the user that you're editing, then verify the password.

```
@app.route('/<int:id>/change-email', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def change_email(id):
    user = User.query.get_or_404(id)

    if user.check_password(form.password.data):
    ...
```